# Update Complex Object which is an element in a DynamoDB record's array

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to PATCH a DynamoDB document. It has a list of elements of type Object which are complex object. I want to replace the element in the array completely. I know the index of the element that needs to be replaced.

I tried converting the object to JSON and then to Map<String, AttributeValue> but conversion to JSON doesn't retain the DynamoDB type.

Seems to use UpdateItem, you need to have Map<String, AttributeValue> of the object that you are trying to update and I am unable to find any straightforward to convert the complex object to Map<String, AttributeValue>

Update: The object at the index I am trying to update is complex. The object itself has Sets and List too. And the SET query expects a Map<String, AttributeValue> meaning somehow this complex object needs to be translated to Map<String,AttributeValue> type. I tried converting this complex object to a JSON and then convert to Map<String, AttributeValue> using `Item.fromJSON(jsonStr)` but when converting the object to JSON, it doesn't retain the information of DynamoDB objects. For example one of my fields in the POJO is this

```
  @DynamoDBTyped(DynamoDBAttributeType.SS)
  private Set<String> c;
```

It updates the object at that index successfully but when I try to read the object back, it fails because its expecting a DynamoDBAttributeType.SS but instead gets a List since JSON treats Sets as just a List

Comment: I was able to solve this using DynamoDBMapperTableModel and using the convert method there

Answer (score 0):

Your post lacks details, but its simple to update a map within a list when you know its position:

```
table.update_item(
  Key={
    'PK': '123'
  },
  UpdateExpression="SET #i[0].#l = :v",
  ExpressionAttributeNames={
    '#i': 'name',
    '#l': 'address'
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues={
    ':v': 'some value',
  },
)
```

You can find more info in the docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.Attributes.html#Expressions.Attributes.NestedAttributes)

Comment: Sorry I will update the question, updating the values themselves are simply but a complex object isn't seems like